# CAPL convert an Byte array to ascii string

Tags: string, byte, ascii, capl

i have an byte array that i need to convert to ascii string before i save it as a system variable.

so i have a byte array like [63 6c 65 61 72]. i need to convert it to 'clear' before i store it in a system variable.

```
    for (i = 0; i < elcount(gByteValue); i++)
    { 
      snprintf(tmp, elcount(tmp), "%.2X ", gByteValue[i]);  // byte to HEX convert
      strncat(gStringValue, tmp, elcount(gStringValue));  // Concatenate HEX value to output string
    }
    write("String : %s", gStringValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for
`DecodeString(char output[], long outputSize, byte input[], long inputSize, dword codepage)`

From CAPL help:

```
includes
{
  #include "Encoding.cin"
}

...
{
  int result;
  char text[10];
  byte stream[6] = {0xC3, 0xA4, 0xC3, 0xB6, 0xC3, 0xBC};
  result = DecodeString(text, 10, stream, 6, CP_UTF8);
  // on German Windows, text is now {‘ä’, ‘ö’, ‘ü’, 0}
  if (result == 0) {
    write(text);
    // Output (on a German Windows): äöü
  }
}
```